# Vue Js + NodeJs Express + Nginx : Unable to connect to NodeJs backend

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, vps

I created a website with Vue JS in front and NodeJS Express in back. I have no issue in development. But once online, the backend is not accessible. We can see that it loads something since I have no error, I only have "Unable to connect because the page took too long to respond".
When launching node, no error is displayed the server launches well.
So, I think it comes from Nginx which is surely misconfigured. However, I am quite new to this system.
Here's what I did as a setup for Nginx:

```
upstream api {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
 
server {
  server_name dreamwebplatform.com www.dreamwebplatform.com;
  root /var/www/dreamweb;
 
  location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
 
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate .....; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key .....; # managed by Certbot
    include ......; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam ......; # managed by Certbot
 
 
}
server {
    if ($host = www.dreamwebplatform.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
 
 
    if ($host = dreamwebplatform.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
 
 
  listen 80;
  server_name dreamwebplatform.com www.dreamwebplatform.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I looked everywhere and tried different configuration but here I am lost.